# Accessing the functions of custom QWidget class using Signals and Slots

Tags: c++, qt

I have a **MediaView** class which inherits QWidget and has GUI components. And i have another class **MediaController** which handles the changes made on the GUI components.

**I need:**
to enable buttons when i receive the signal finishedLoadingFile()

So here is a sample how my class looks:

**MediaView.cpp**

```
MediaView::MediaView(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
   m_controller = new MediaController(this);

   m_btnPlay = new QPushButton(m_mediaButtons);
   m_btnPlay->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/play.png"));
   m_btnPlay->setIconSize(QSize(32, 32));
   m_btnPlay->move(100, 10);
   m_btnPlay->resize(39, 38);
   m_btnPlay->setToolTip("Play");

   m_btnPause = new QPushButton(m_mediaButtons);
   m_btnPause->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/pause.png"));
   m_btnPause->setIconSize(QSize(32, 32));
   m_btnPause->move(150, 10);
   m_btnPause->resize(39, 38);
   m_btnPause->setToolTip("Pause");

   m_btnPlay->setEnabled(false);
   m_btnPause->setEnabled(false);

   connect(m_btnOpen, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), m_controller, SLOT(loadFile()));
   connect(m_btnPlay,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),m_controller,SLOT(buttonPlayClicked()));
   connect(m_btnPause,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),m_controller,SLOT(buttonPauseClicked()));
}

void MediaView::enableButtons()
{
   m_btnPlay->setEnabled(true);
   m_btnPause->setEnabled(true);
}
```

**MediaController.cpp**

```
MediaController::MediaController(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    MediaView* view = new MediaView(this); //loop here
    connect(this, SIGNAL(loadingFileFinished(), view, SLOT(enableButtons()));
}

void MediaController::loadFile()
{
    m_filePath = "";

    m_filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Choose a .txt file with paths to gtt streams", QString(),
             QString("text file(*.txt)"));

    if (m_filePath.isEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }

    m_file = "";
    m_file.append(m_filePath.toLocal8Bit().constData());

    emit finishedLoadingFile();
}
```

**Issue:**

I wish to call the enableButtons() in the MediaView class. But when i instantiate the MediaView class inside MediaController, app crashes because they keep calling each others constructors in a loop. Reason being, they both communicate using signals and slots so i need to instantiate objects of their respective classes.

**Alternatives:**

I would like to know whether if it is possible to access the widgets from MediaController class so that i can use them there itself?
If not, a better way to communicate between view and controller?

Comment: You say you have a loop and you do not show the loop. You must provide a code that allows us to reproduce the error, that in SO is called [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You could share your project to be able to test it via github, drive or similar.

Comment: I find it strange that you create a MediaView within MediaController, and a MediaController within MediaView, those objects are different.

Comment: @eyllanesc i have to create them because i need the instances of them in connect() function as m_controller and view.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each MediaView creates a MediaController, and each MediaController creates another MediaView, that generates the infinite loop, the appropriate thing is to create a MediaController in MediaView and make the connections:

```
MediaView::MediaView(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
   m_controller = new MediaController(this);
   connect(m_controller, &MediaController::loadingFileFinished, this, &MediaView::enableButtons);
   [...]
}
```

it is not necessary to create a new `MediaView` within `MediaController`.

If you want to access `MediaView` from `MediaController` you can do it through parent since `MediaView` is the parent of `MediaController`:

**MediaController.h**

```
MediaView *view;
```

**MediaController.cpp**

```
MediaController::MediaController(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    view = qobject_cast<QMediaView *>(parent);
    //or 
    // connect(this, &MediaController::loadingFileFinished, view, &MediaView::enableButtons);
}
```

Comment: thank you @eyllanesc! I guess now i understand where i was going wrong. I will mark it as answer after i try it.

Comment: if you want to connect the slots from outside the class these should be public, the default signals are public. :P

Comment: I tried the first option and it worked great! thank you! Could you briefly explain what qobject_cast is doing here? Because if i call the constructor MediaController and pass the MediaView as parent why do i need to convert it again ? May be i am missing something here.